# Computing the fundamental group with Seifert-van-Kampen

Tags: algebraic-topology

I need some help to solve this:

Let $X := \Bbb R^{2} \setminus \lbrace x_{0},x_{1}\rbrace$, where $x_{0}$ $\not= x_{1}$ and $x_{0},x_{1} \in \Bbb R^{2} \setminus \lbrace \left(0,0\right)\rbrace$. Compute the fundamental group $\pi_{1} \big(X,(0,0)\big).$

My first idea was:

We can split up the space $X$. The intersection should have the trivial fundamental group, i.e. $\Bbb R^{2}$.

I don't see how to go on. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: $X$ is homotopy equivalent to the one-point union of two circles. Then van-Kampen shows the result, since the intersection of the two circles is a point.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Show that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{x_0, x_1\}$ deformation retracts onto the wedge sum of two circles.

Alternatively, consider two half-planes, each containing one of $\{x_0, x_1\}$ and intersecting in a strip. Apply the Van Kampen theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, we may suppose that $x_0=(\frac23,0)$ and $x_1=(-\frac23,0).$ (Why?) Take $$U=\{x\in\Bbb R^2: \lVert x-x_2\rVert>1\}$$ and $$V=\{x\in\Bbb R^2: \lVert x-x_1\rVert>1\},$$ where $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is the usual Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^2$. Then $U,V$ are open, $(0,0)\in U\cap V,$ $\Bbb R^2=U\cup V$, and each of $U,V,U\cap V$ is path-connected. Observe then that $\pi_1\bigl(U,(0,0)\bigr)=\pi_1\bigl(V,(0,0)\bigr)=\Bbb Z,$ and that $\pi_1\bigl(U\cap V,(0,0)\bigr)$ is the zero group. What can we then conclude from Seifert-van Kampen?

Comment: Then we can conclude from Seifert-van Kampen: $\pi_{1}(X) = \Bbb Z \ast_{1} \Bbb Z = \Bbb Z \ast \Bbb Z$. Is that the point you wanted to stress?

Comment: Precisely what I was getting at!

Comment: Is this the whole computation of the fundamental group? Every time when it looks simple, I'm a bit unsure

Comment: Yep. That's all we have to do, here.